# org.eclipse.ui.startup in use with WindowListener - first activation not caught

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Greetings fellow Stackoverflowians,

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and I want to add a listener to the `ProjectExplorer` Eclipse View, and this listener needs to be added before the user does anything, but after the GUI has been generated.
Right on startup, though, the `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` returns `null` (d'oh, the window isn't activated) so therefore I add to the already created `Workbench` a `WindowListener`

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWindowListener(new IWindowListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowActivated(IWorkbenchWindow activatedWindow) {
                //do stuff here
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(IWorkbenchWindow arg0) {
                //remove stuff here
            }
            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(IWorkbenchWindow arg0) {
                // stub
            }
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(IWorkbenchWindow arg0) {
                //stub
            }
        });
```

Now the problem that I've come across is that even though the `ActiveWorkbenchWindow` is populated, the `windowActivated()` method from the `WindowListener` is not called :(

Funnily enough, when I click on another window, then I click back on the application window, the `windowActivated()` method is called... therefore the listener was indeed registered.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19979141/2893073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've succeeded in not using the `WindowListener` anymore on the `Workbench`, so instead of adding it in the `earlyStartup()` method of my `IStartup` implementation, I've done this:

```
public class StartupHook implements IStartup {
    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() { 
        IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()[0];
        ISelectionListener projectListener = new ProjectSelectionListener();
        window.getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(projectListener);
    }

}
```

The trick is that despite there being multiple windows opened on startup, only one is represented, that includes all the views, hence it is reasonable to access: `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()[0]`

Presto, worked around the active window not being in the `getActiveWindow()` method of the `Workbench`

Answer (score 3):

You could use overrides of the `postWindowCreate` or `postWindowOpen` methods of `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` to set this up.

Comment: I just realized I could access the PlatformUI.getWorkbench.getWorkbenchWindows()[0], whereas it always is only one window, hence it is the one that will be activated, I've tested this on Windows 7 with multiple visible windows in the same workbench... Anyway, I don't have access to the WindowAdvisor...